# Position fixed left property not working from the browser left inside multiple positions properties

Tags: html, css

Hi I have below html and css code where `.first` `.second` `.third` elements css coming dyanamically from plugings and `.fourth` element is adding later on click which having css of `position:fix` and `left:0`
but now because of parent css there are multiple position properties are already added that's why left property taking from the container instead of taking from the browser. Any way to achieve this?

```css
.first {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1300;
    position: fixed;
}
.second {
    left: auto !important;
    transform: scale(1) !important;
    right: 0;
    width: 25%;
    border-radius: 0;
    min-height: 90vh;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 16px;
    max-width: calc(100% - 32px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: calc(100% - 32px);
}
.third {
    padding: 8px 1px 0;
    height: 92vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background:blue;
}
.fourth{
    background:red;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 400px;
    transition: 1s all;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
<div class="second">
<div class="third">
<div class="fourth">
<p>Fourth Div</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the expected output? you want the 4th div to move completely left?

Comment: this is due to the transform. The duplicate talks about filter but I am listing all the propertirs doing the same at the bottom of the answer

Comment: @Manjuboyz exactly that's what I want I want to left 0 to browser

Comment: @TemaniAfif let me check

Comment: @TemaniAfif filter
transform ref
backdrop-filter ref
perspective ref
contain ref
transform-style ref
will-change how can these properties to help to move last div completely left

Comment: no one of the properties will help your to move. The duplicate is explaining why you *cannot* move it because you have the transform property that you need to remove

Comment: You mean this  transform: scale(1) !important; ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm using reactjs will check another solution to implement this functionality

Comment: @TemaniAfif ohh by removing transform it works, Thanks learnt something new.